# Filtering specific word after a symbol

Tags: regex, emeditor

So currently im trying to filter a large list with different domains such as .com, .ca, ect
But filtering to just .ca doesn't work because it filters emails that have any type of .ca

For example a list such as

1. Blue@gmail.com
2. Red.carp@yahoo.com
3. Black@live.ca
4. Orange@live.ca
5. Green.candice@hotmail.com

I was wondering if I could filter anything after the symbol @ with a specific word to just the .ca domains after the @ symbol

I've only really tried using .ca as the filter since i don't have much knowledge in regex

Comment: I have never used emeditor, but the regex you are looking for is `'@.*\.ca$'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0):

The regex you can use to specify that the line must end with `.ca` is `\.ca$`. The `$` symbol indicates the end of line.

Make sure that you enable Use Regular Expressions.

[image]